# Show keyboard for div with contenteditable="true" in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, contenteditable

I have a div with contenteditable="true". How can I set focus on this div via javascript(if it possible on pure js, without jquery)?

Comment: "(if it possible on pure js, without jquery)?" jQuery is written in pure JS, so how could that be possible with jQuery, but not in pure JS?

Comment: @Reinmar I'm sure he meant “I'd rather like a pure JS answer”.

Answer (score 7):

Prior to iOS 6 this wasn't possible, but thankfully they've changed that. You can't do it in general for a website, but if you are embedding a `UIWebView` in your application you can do it now:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
webView.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction = NO;
```

Then your `element.focus()` will work and bring up the keyboard as desired.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction

More info on what changed with iOS 6 & WebKit:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012166-CH1-SW19

Comment: Thanks a ton! However, surprisingly it only works when `keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction` is set to `NO` only from code and not from the designer(xib)!!

Answer (score 1):

supposing the id of the contenteditable div is 'editableDiv',

```
document.getElementById('editableDiv').focus();
```

**Updates
Could you try with something inside the div?

```
<script>
function showKeyboard() {
    document.getElementById('content').focus();
}
</script>
<body onLoad="showKeyboard()">
    <div id="content" contenteditable="true" height="1000">&nbsp;</div>  
</body>
```

Comment: I have tried to do it via this code http://pastie.org/3626420 . But it doesn't work in iOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible in iOS now :( https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3016